# Classification tree cross val error increasing but test error decreasing

Tags: cross-validation, cart, rpart

My data has 5000 points. I predict a categorical outcome using 10 numeric variables.

I build a tree with 3500 points (in R using rpart) using cross validation and plotcp shows this below ...

I have set cp = 0 so it would keep growing for even the smallest amount of improvement of fit.
This looks like overfitting to me. But my accuracy the on unused 1500 data points for the full tree with 200+ nodes is 59.62%, and the tree pruned to min x-val error (56 nodes) has only 59.42% accuracy.

What can explain the contradictory movement of test set and x-val accuracy?

[image]